# Symfony - запретить Doctrine создавать миграцыю на связь

Tags: symfony, doctrine2, doctrine-orm

Хочу запретить доктрине строить FK по колонкам, так как связь осуществятся на уровне кода, а выхлоп от нее мешает разрабатывать. Можно ли такое реализовать?

```
 /**
     * @var Product
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Product",
     *      inversedBy="warehouse",
     *      orphanRemoval=true,
     *      cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private ?Product $product;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему!

Делаем diff миграции и со всего прочего удаляем генерируемую связь где FK равняется id=id, поднимаем миграцию, и теперь, добавляем названия таблицы в **doctrine.dbal.connections.default.schema_filter** или туда где у вас производятся настройки фильтра схемы, данный мув был сделан чтобы не было выхлопов в миграцию по связи